# Python -c bash swtich newline

Tags: python, bash, command-line-interface

I'd like to run the command:

```
print "hello"
print "world!"
```

from python with the `-c` switch from bash, something like this:

```
python -c 'print "hello" \n print "world"'
```

But I can't figure out what the correct newline character should be in the string after the `-c` switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
python -c 'print "hello"; print "world"'
```

Answer (score 1):

some python statements cannot be written in one line, so I recommend this:

```sh
python -c '
print "hello"
print "world"
'
```

in this way statements such as `for` can be appeared.

Answer (score -1):

`python -c 'print "hello\nworld"'`

Comment: It's the same effect but not the same thing, I want two commands